# error when calling batch file with no arguments

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I have a very simple batch script:

```
@echo off

if %1 == a goto AA
if %1 == b goto BB
goto end

:AA
echo a
goto end

:BB
echo b
goto end

:END
echo on
```

If I call it with an argument `test.bat a`, I get what I expected, but if I call it without any arguments `test.bat`, I get `goto was unexpected at this time.` and the offending line is `if %1 == a goto AA`.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line `if %1 == a goto AA` will become `if == a goto AA` when there are no arguments.

if you use `if .%1 == .a goto AA` then the line becomes `if . == .a goto AA` with no arguments, and windows does not throw an error of having nothing between `if` and `==`

Answer (score 2):

Enclose both the variable and the value in quotes in each comparison.

```
if "%1" == "a" goto AA
if "%1" == "b" goto BB
goto end
```